# Asus ROG Strix Scar GL703GS WiFi crashed

Tags: laptop, wifi

I have an Asus ROG Strix Scar GL703GS laptop, and following a cancelled download on Google Chrome, my WiFi card crashed. I do not know if this incident is related to the cancellation of the download, but it happened at that moment.

I tried to reinstall the drivers of the WiFi card (Wireless radio control driver V1.0.0.9, 164.09 KBytes). Without success.

How can get the WiFi working again?

Comment: I think this question about troubleshooting the wifi should be moved to another community like Super User or similar.